# Handlebars, при выборе пользователя из тега select добавить соответствующие значения в тег div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars, sequelize.js

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, из базы данных подставляю значения с помощь Handlebars в тег select, согласно этому значению в двух div  передать другие значения(например: выбрав фамилию, нужно передать имя и отчество соответствующие этой фамилии) 
мой стек nodejs, Handlebars, mysql, sequelize
код user.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: { autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    fio: { type: Sequelize.STRING,notEmpty: true},
    login: { type: Sequelize.STRING,notEmpty: true},
    telephone: {type:Sequelize.STRING},
    password : {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false },
    type: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    state: {type: Sequelize.STRING('1','0'),defaultValue:'1' }
```

});

```
return User;
```

}

controller.js:

```
exports.users = function (req, res) {

db.user.findAll({
    fio: 'fio ASC'

}).then(function (data) {
    var hbsObject = {
        users: data
    };
    res.render('users', hbsObject);


});
```

}

user.hbs:

```
<label for="users">users:</label>
<select name="users">
    {{#each users}}
        <option  value={{this.id}}>{{this.fio}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select><br>
```

В двух последних div нужно показать  Имя и Фамилию выбранного пользователя в теге select.
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Посмотрите, что пишет `console.log(data)` в обработчике ответа от бд, локализуйте проблему, обновите/удалите вопрос.

Comment: Не известно когда нужно выводить, только при рендере или же динамически при смене пользователя. Если это должен обработать сервер, то предлагаю решить на сервере через `filter` или `lodash.find`, разницы нету, будет это в Handlebars происходить или же непосредственно перед рендером, всё равно обрабатывает сервер. К тому же вычислить пользователя будет удобнее непосредственно на сервере и передать уже готовый объект с данными о пользователе. Если клиент, то ванила и jquery вам в помощь, слушаем через `.on('change')` и так же высчитываем и подставляем в нужные `div`.

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан нужно выводить при  динамически при смене пользователя, как в див подставить я понимаю, я неочень понимаю можно как то выводить без запроса к серверу